# Sum multiple TIME()'s

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have this table of scores:

```
---------
| TIME  | 
---------
| L4:10 |
| W2:32 |
| L2:23 |
| L6:10 |
| W1:10 |
---------
```

To convert a score to an actual time, I use:

```
=TIME(0, MID(A1, 2, 1), MID(A1, 4, 2))  [ which outputs 00:04:10 for the A1 ]
```

Is there any way to sum all these totals at once without creating new cells?

*(Note: I cannot remove the L's and W's from the original cells)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider wrapping it up into `ARRAYFORMULA` this way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(TIME(0, MID(A1:A5, 2, 1), MID(A1:A5, 4, 2))))
```

This will sum all the values in A1:A5 range into one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Very slightly shorter:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(1*regexreplace(A1:A5,"L|W","00:")))
```

Returns `00:16:25` when formatted accordingly.